# Вопрос про порядок исполнения кода

Tags: javascript

Может ли `код1` выполниться раньше чем `код2`?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/', true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // код1
}
// код2
```

Comment: при третьем параметре `open`  `true` - нет

Comment: @Igor А почему? И кстати он по умолчанию `true`.

Comment: потому что при асинхронных операциях, текущий блок должен выполниться до конца. прежде чем управление перейдет к выполнению callback для асинхронной операции

Comment: @Grundy А ещё вопрос: что должно идти раньше `xhr.send();` или назначение обработчика `xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){}`?

Comment: вообще назначение обработчика, но я пробовал и твой вариант, тоже сработало

Comment: @Grundy но лучше сначала наверно обработчик назначить, а уже потом инициировать событие

Comment: интуитивно, мне тоже всегда хочется так сделать (и делаю). На удивление, в большинстве примеров порядок действий - как в вопросе.

Comment: @Igor м.б. надеются что так быстрее будет работать. пока на сервере обрабатывается запрос мы назначаем обработчик.